# Updating environmental variables in Django while running

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I have an app that makes some API calls, I store my API secret in an .env file which is loaded into the Django settings file which works fine.

Once a month I have to update the API secret, I have the code to check for expiry and get the new key, my question is how to handle that within my running Django app. As it stands I can load the .env file in and do a find a replace on the key but that feels like a bad way to go about it in addition to not taking effect until the next time the app is restarted.

When you have secrets that change over time whats best practice on updating and storing them?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your settings dynamically in your database. There are a bunch of libraries which provide such opportunity, but the one I personally use in production is [django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance)